# Find $o(b)$ if $aba^{-1}=b^2$ and given that $a^5=e$

Tags: group-theory

If in a group $G$, $a^5=e$, $aba^{-1}=b^2$ for some $a,b\in{G}$. Find $o(b)$.

I wrote $aba^{-1}=b^2$ as $ab=b^2a$. Then $(ab)^5=(b^2a)^5$ but then I am stucked up.

Comment: Where did you pick up writing $_0(g)$? I have seen $o(g)$ and $|g|$, but this notation is new to me.

Comment: @user1729 some latex mistake.... I don't know code for your first notation. Please tell me.

Comment: It is just the letter o. 'o(g)'

Comment: @user1729 Thanks...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Hint:
$$
a^2ba^{-2}=a(aba^{-1})a^{-1}=ab^2a^{-1}=aba^{-1}aba^{-1}=(aba^{-1})(aba^{-1})=b^2b^2=b^4.
$$
Repeat until you have calculated $a^5ba^{-5}$. Then use other given facts.

---

The OP indicated that they solved the question. Here's a spoilerized solution:

> After a few more iterations we get that $a^5ba^{-5}=b^{2^5}=b^{32}.$ Given that $a^5=e$ the l.h.s. is equal to $b$. Thus $b=b^{32}$, or $b^{31}=1$. As $31$ is a prime, we can conclude that either $o(b)=31$ or $o(b)=1$.

Comment: But how tongo further? Please explain

Comment: Next calculate $a^3ba^{-3}$.

Comment: how? I got it is equal to $ab^4a^{-1}$ but not in pure powers of $b$.

Comment: Did you check what I did in the third step?

Comment: yeah....got it..thanks

Comment: Great! Well done, @SatvikMashkaria!

Comment: Nice solution! You derived that $o(b)=31$ or $o(b)=1$. This "or" worries since I thought that an element has unique order.

Comment: @RFZ Yeah. But there's nothing I can do about it! If $b=1$ it has order $1$ and the equation is satisfied! Two alternatives for $o(b)$ remain, and we are not given enough information to narrow it down further.

Comment: It is also easy to describe a situation where $b$ has order $31$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, you mean $b=e$ instead of $b=1$ right?

Comment: Correct @RFZ. I'm used to denoting the neutral element by $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Given $a^5=e$ 
$aba^{-1}=b^2$
Squaring both sides 
$ab^2a^{-1}=b^4$
Again re substituting value of $b^2$ in  above we get 
 
$a^2ba^{-2}=b^4$
 Similarly we get  
 
$a^3ba^{-3}=b^8$
$a^4ba^{-4}=b^{16}$
$a^5ba^{-5}=b^{32}$
 This leads to order of b as 31.

Answer (score 0):

I am reading "Topics in Algebra 2nd Edition" by I. N. Herstein.
This problem is the same problem as Problem 37 on p.49 in Herstein's book.

> If $a=e$, then $b=ebe^{-1}=aba^{-1}=b^2$.
> So, $b=e$ must hold.
> And $a=b=e$ satisfies the conditions $a^5=e$ and $aba^{-1}=b^2$.

> So I think the answer of this problem is the following:
> If $a=e$, then $o(b)=1$.
> If $a\ne e$, then $o(b)=31$.